# how can I fix "1 leaked semaphore objects to clean up at shutdown" error on Mac M1

Tags: python

I am using Apple Mac M1:

```
OS: MacOS Monterey

Python 3.9.13
```

I want to implement a semantic search using `SentenceTransformer`.

Here is my code:

```
from sentence_transformers import SentenceTransformer
import faiss
from pprint import pprint
import time

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

 

def load_index():
    index = faiss.read_index("movie_plot.index")
    return index


def fetch_movie_info(dataframe_idx):
    info = df.iloc[dataframe_idx]
    meta_dict = dict()
    meta_dict['Title'] = info['Title']
    meta_dict['Plot'] = info['Plot'][:500]
    return meta_dict
    
def search(query, top_k, index, model):
    print("starting search!")
    t=time.time()
    query_vector = model.encode([query])
    top_k = index.search(query_vector, top_k)
    print('>>>> Results in Total Time: {}'.format(time.time()-t))
    top_k_ids = top_k[1].tolist()[0]
    top_k_ids = list(np.unique(top_k_ids))
    results =  [fetch_movie_info(idx) for idx in top_k_ids]
    return results


def main():
    # GET MODEL
    model = SentenceTransformer('msmarco-distilbert-base-dot-prod-v3')
    print("model set!")
    #GET INDEX
    index = load_index()
    print("index loaded!")
    query="Artificial Intelligence based action movie"
    results=search(query, top_k=5, index=index, model=model)
    print("\n")
    for result in results:
        print('\t',result)

main()
```

when i run the code above it gets stuck at this error

> > /opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/envs/searchapp/lib/python3.9/multiprocessing/resource_tracker.py:216: UserWarning: resource_tracker: There appear to be 1 leaked semaphore objects to clean up at shutdown
> > warnings.warn('resource_tracker: There appear to be %d '

what is causing this and how can I fix it?

Comment: It's a resource leak and it's unlikely that you can cause it by your Python code. Extract a [mcve] and file a bug report.

Comment: Here is same issue (with [coremltools](https://github.com/apple/coremltools) 5.2)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, upgrading to Python 3.9 solved it in my case.

It looks like it is an official bug: https://bugs.python.org/issue45209

Comment: I still have this issue with python 3.9.16

Comment: It happens to me in `Python 3.8.12` and  `Python 3.9.2`
https://github.com/UKPLab/sentence-transformers/issues/1319

Answer (score 1):

Check your memory utilisation. You might be out of memory.

Since you're using a pretrained model for inference/prediction, you can reduce the memory requirements of the model by avoiding computation of the gradients. Gradients are only used for training the model typically.

You can wrap your model call with `torch.no_grad` like so:

```
with torch.no_grad():
    query_vector = model.encode([query])
```

You can also reduce the memory utilisation a model by reducing the batch size (i.e. number of samples passed to the model at one time), but that doesn't seem to apply here.

Comment: This ideally makes sense, but it does not fix this specific issue.